# index.handler is undefined or not exported when testing Lambda function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a JS script `index.js` that takes one variable input `ipAddress` but it's giving me the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```

my zipped archive looks like this once unzipped:

```
.
├── index.js
├── node_modules/
└── package.json
```

The script does work locally:

```
> node index.js 158.140.127.123
Found ipAddress match
Bucket uploaded successfully at /blocklist-158.140.127.123
```

But not when importing the zip to Lambda

UPDATE: index.js content:

```
// Usage: index.js x.x.x.x
'use strict';

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-east-1"
});

// Get ipAddress from user argument (will eventually get input from sns)
var ipAddress = process.argv[2]

// Get geolocation from ipAddress
function getIpAddressGeo(ipAddress) {
    const geoip = require('geoip-lite');
    var geo = geoip.lookup(ipAddress);

    return geo;
};

async function getIpMatchBool() {
    const request = require('request');
    const promise = require('promise');

    var lookupUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/firehol/blocklist-ipsets/master/bi_sip_0_1d.ipset";

    // This should only create a bucket if getIpMatchBool returns true
    function createS3IpListing(ipAddress) {
        var date = Date.now();
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({
            apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        });
        const bucketParams = {
            Bucket: `blocklist-${ipAddress}`
        };
        s3.createBucket(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
                console.log(`Bucket uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`);
            }
        });

        // createFile not returning - working on this now
        const createFile = (geo = getIpAddressGeo()) => {
            const fs = require('fs');

            fs.readFile(date, (err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                const params = {
                    Bucket: bucketParams.Bucket,
                    Key: date,
                    Body: JSON.stringify(data, geo)
                };
                s3.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) {
                    if (s3Err) throw s3Err
                    console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
                });
            });
            return createFile(geo)

        };

    };

    // This RegEx does not account for the differance between 10 & 10.x.x.x - need to fix
    var re = new RegExp(ipAddress.replace(/\./g, '\\.'), 'gi');

    const issueRequest = () => {
        return new promise(() => {
            request(lookupUrl, function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    if (body.search(re) == -1) {
                        console.log("No ipAddress match");
                    } else {
                        createS3IpListing(ipAddress);
                        console.log("Found ipAddress match");
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    }
    return await issueRequest();
}

getIpMatchBool(ipAddress)
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `index.js`?

Comment: Have you defined a `handler` function in the `index.js` file?

Comment: @jellycsc Just updated it with the index.js contents

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I do not believe that I have

Comment: You must export the handler. I think that's mandatory.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein would it just look something like this at the bottom of the code: `module.exports = getIpMatchBool(ipAddress);`? I have tried some variations of this and still receive `Cannot find module 'exports'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access your variable through process.arg. Try using exports.handler the with the event parameter. The handler is what the lambda function returns/executes by default. You can find the documentation [here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

Comment: I have also tried some variations of the following `exports.handler = async function(event) {
    return getIpMatchBool(ipAddress)
}` and receive `Cannot find module 'exports'`

Comment: huh... That's strange. Try modifying a blank lambda in the GUI instead of uploading your own and see if it still throws that error. Maybe you are not exporting it correctly. Just modify the existing template as it already has the export defined properly.